# How to Use Modal Pop-Ups with ASP.Net MVC and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, jqmodal

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to use jQuery modal popups with asp.net MVC and AJAX.

Has anyone managed to do this well?

I've tried JQModal and JQuery UI but haven't managed to find any good samples or tutorials yet.

Comment: "with limited success" - why limited? what obstacles did you run into?

Comment: I tried JQModal and can get that to fire through the controller but not inside a popup window.

I also tried jQuery UI and managed to get the popup firing correctly but not using AJAX aor going through controller.

I never posted code samples as I don't want to guide anyone's response if neither of these are the best way.

Comment: Code samples are always helpful because they show your goal, help easily setup and reproduce the problem and get an answer faster.

Comment: Thanks, OK I'll post tomorrow as on my home PC now.  I want to use to click on a row in a list or grid, popup the correct edit and have the mainpage refreshed on the save of the pop-up.

I think I'm hopefully close with JQModal so I'll start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Davy wrote, "It is possible then to click on a row, pop-up with filled editable controls, validate and save and then redirect back to the list page?

Hi Davy,

I also have implemented jQuery UI dialogs in my MVC forms.  The hard part is not the dialog, but the ajax calls.  Data-wise, a jQuery dialog (recommended) is nothing more than another DIV tag in your form.

When you declare the Dialog options, you can specify buttons, with names and a function they execute.  In you modal dialog, add something like:

```
buttons: { "Add row": function() { yourAjaxFunction(); }
```

in the function yourAjaxFunction(), you can get your values with something like:

```
var myFields = $("#MyDialog").serialize();
```

or

```
var myFieldsArray = $("#MyDialog").serializeArray();
```

to get the names and values of your fields, then validate them, and then post "myFields" to your controller with a:

```
$.ajax(<your options here>);
```

or a :

```
$.post(<your options here>)
```

Your MVC controller will happily convert values specified in the querystring to matching named method parameters, save them, and then return a response (either a Partial View or JSON or text).

The [Ajax reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) in jQuery is very helpful for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the jqueryui dialog modals with ASP.Net MVC and it works out very well. These modals are very easy to implement in my opinion. Take a look at these dialog modals here: [jqueryui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: Thanks, I can get the pop-up coming up using this method but it ignores the controller.  

It is possible then to click on a row, pop-up with filled editable controls, validate and save and then redirect back to the list page?

Comment: If I follow you correctly, you want to click on a row of a grid to open a dialog window with a pre-populated form that has field validation.
If it is a possibility for you, I'd look at MVC 2 Preview 2. There are couple tidbits which could help you a great deal here (http://haacked.com/archive/2009/10/01/asp.net-mvc-preview-2-released.aspx). One is the jQuery validation library. You can set up validation rules server side (model validation metadata) and emit them out to the client-side. A bigger piece is you can generate the form dynamically using the model metadata to dictate form fields.